# How to get Methods from KClass in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, class, kotlin, reflection

In java when i have a Class<> instance, i have the *getMethod* that return a Method and it is very easy to use.
As i can see Kotlin makes life harder because such a method doesn't exist. is there a nice way to get a specific method beside of turning the *KClass* to *Class* and then using it exactly as in Java?

Comment: Do you need to get a method by String name? Otherwise, you can just use `::methodName`.

Comment: Otherwise, you can get a KCallable using `class.members.single { it.name == "theFunctionName" }`

Comment: yes I need by name. Incidentally, the **::methodName** doesn't work when i tried the following:
 val str:String ="dsasa"
    var kclass : KClass<out String> = str::class
    str.toUpperCase()

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you tried, probably because of comment formatting, but you could edit it into the question if you want to ask about it too.

Comment: @Tenfour04, I understand all! thank you! you should write an official answer so i can reward you :) You are the master of the lambda expression. Just two  small and important questions, 1. Does this syntax bound the instance to the function? 2.Does members collection includes methods of *companion* object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing you have this class:

```
class Test {
    fun sayHello() = println("Hello world")

    companion object {
        fun foo() = println("foo")
    }
}
```

This gives you a function instance you can call with `invoke()` (which is an operator function, so you can just use parentheses like with any other function. If you get the function using the class name like this, it is not bound to an instance. So you pass the instance as the first parameter when invoking. (If `sayHello()` had additional parameters, they would just go after the first parameter of Test.)

```
val sayHelloFunction = Test::sayHello
val test = Test()
sayHelloFunction(test) // same as calling test.sayHello()
```

You can also get a function reference that's bound to an instance like this. It cannot be called on other instances of Test.

```
val test = Test()
val sayHelloFunction = test::sayHello
sayHelloFunction() // same as calling test.sayHello()
```

The above method doesn't require the Kotlin reflection library.

To get a member by String name, there isn't a specific function like Java's `getMethod`, so you have to pick it out of the list of members, which are KCallable. KCallable doesn't have the `operator fun invoke`, so you have to use `call` to call it, or cast it to a specific function type (in this case it would be `(Test) -> Unit`).

```
val sayHelloCallable = Test::class.members.single { it.name == "sayHello" }
val test = Test()
sayHelloCallable.call(test) // same as calling test.sayHello()
```

This *does not* list the members of the companion object, as that is a different class. For that you would have to get the companion's class:

```
Test.Companion::class.members.single { it.name == "foo" }
```

I don't know if there's a way to get an instance bound version by name.

As for why there's no convenient `getMethod` function for KClass, I can only guess that because Kotlin classes have so many different types of members (properties, functions, delegates, backing fields), that maybe they want to limit API bloat and feel that the inline filtering functions like `single` are adequate.

Comment: thanks a lot. Great explanation. Maybe you can explain why saying: *"The above method doesn't require the Kotlin reflection library*". Why does the first example using reflection and the second one doesn't use?

Comment: The less commonly used reflection features are in that library for the sake of reducing the compiled size of Kotlin apps.

Comment: you are saying the "above mehod", did you mean the "above **methods**? because the **two** first examples looks the same  (apart of the bounding).. In addition the example  are like the examples in the **https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html** link that is called "Reflection". So why do you say it doesn't use reflection? Does it reflection without a library?

Comment: Yes. `::` is always okay to use without the reflection library.

Comment: sorry for opening a question after more than a week.. But i have opened the KFunction source code and didn't find there any reference to *operator invoke*, so maybe you can tell me how does the *Function* Instance can be called with invoke (or with parentheses)?

Comment: I’m on my phone so just going off memory. I don’t think a function reference is the same thing as a KFunction instance. In Kotlin, functions are first class objects. KFunction is a reflection class that has data about some function, and you only can get a KFunction indirectly through a KClass, not by directly referencing a function with `::`.

Comment: ,also from memory you knows everything :)  ... What do you mean when saying *"first class object"*? Does *function* has *invoke* method?

Comment: I mean it’s just a part of the language, not treated like a class that needs an invoke function. Kind of the way primitives are in Java.

Comment: i have a problem :)  i have already have a *KClass* and i want to get a static (companion method) from the *KClass* instance. In the example you used an Instance (Test) and than wrote: **Test.Companion::class.members.single { it.name == "foo" }**  , but what can i do with a *KClass*, only going to java option and get a *Class* from the *KClass* and then using java method *getMethod*?

Comment: You could do `someKClass.companionObject` to get the KClass of the companion, and `.companionObjectInstance` to get the actual companion object you will have to use as the receiver if you want to call the function.

Comment: @ Tenfour04 *single* method gets only a lambda expression as a parameter, but if the method i'm interested in is overloaded... How should I add the parameters?

Comment: You can put anything you want in the `single` lambda to select what you want, for instance `.single { it.name == "foo" && it.parameters.size == 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Class` from a `KClass`, you just call [`.java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html) on it (and [`.kotlin`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.lang.-class/kotlin.html) to go the other way).